# Get value of td which is in form table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel, forms

I have table in HTML form, and I want to get the value of `<td>` for that special row input,

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="font-weight-bold" style="width: 10%">ID</th>
            <th class="text-left font-weight-bold" style="width: 20%">Invoice No.</th>
            <th class="text-left font-weight-bold" style="width: 20%">Amount</th>
            <th class="text-left font-weight-bold" style="width: 15%">Unpaid</th>
            <th class="text-left font-weight-bold" style="width: 25%">Payment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ( $invoices as $i )
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $i->invoice_id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $i->invoice_number }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $i->invoice_amount }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $i->pending_amount }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            {{ $currencySymbol }}
                        </span></a>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control payment_amount" name="payment_amount_invoice[]" id="payment_amount_invoice" value=""/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is js...

```
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/sales/payments/save',
                    data: $("#paymentForm").serialize(),
                    success: function(data)
                    {....
```

How can I get `invoice_id` for that specific input of `payment_amount_invoice`?

Thank you,

Comment: One way could be adding a `data-invoiceid={{ $i->invoice_id }}` attribute to the text input, so that you can retrieve it with `element.dataset.invoiceid`. Anyway, please pay attention as your code is going to create several HTML element with the same `id` attribute (`payment_amount_invoice`).

Comment: where is `paymentForm` ?

Comment: @Swati, not shown here, but table is part of  ```paymentForm```

Comment: Your input are inside loop so there will be mutliple input which one do you need ?

Comment: @Swati, yes, I need to send ```invoice_id``` which is related to ```payment_amount_invoice```

Comment: @secan, how can I pass ```data-invoiceid```, to the server?

Comment: You can't have same `id` in a loop. They need to be unique. "*I need to send invoice_id which is related to payment_amount_invoice"* - every input will have id `payment_amount_invoice` so it's not clear what you want. Are you clicking a specific row or something?

Comment: @TJ, I know about id and is corrected already, btw got work with hidden filed and serverside script.

Answer (score 0):

So here is way,

Added hidden input field as `invoice_id` and used same array for checking in server-side,

```
<td>
   {{ $i->invoice_id }}
   <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id[]" value="{{ $i->invoice_id }}"> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the HTML part of your script to replace the laravel templating with a short JavaScript script.

After the user clicks the "save" button the important stuff happens here:

```
Object.values(frm)
  .map(e=> ({id:e.closest("tr").children[0].innerText, amnt:e.value})  )
```

The input objects of form `frm` are put into an array and are then processed through a `.map()` call: the `id` for each input is taken from the `.textContent` of the first `<td>` in the current line and the `amnt` is taken from the input element's `.value`.

```js
const tb=document.querySelector("tbody"), currencySymbol="€",
      na="invoice_id,invoice_number,invoice_amount,pending_amount".split(","),
      data=[[101,202101,200,200],[102,202103,50,50],[103,202104,300,100],
            [104,202107,123,123],[105,202108,20,0],[106,202109,93,43]];
      data.forEach((e,i,ar)=>ar[i]=(e.reduce((a,c,j)=>(a[na[j]]=c,a),{} )));
tb.innerHTML=data.map(i=>
`<tr><td>${i.invoice_id}</td>
  <td>${i.invoice_number}</td>
  <td>${i.invoice_amount}</td>
  <td>${i.pending_amount}</td>
  <td><label><input type="text" name="payment_amount_invoice[]"
   value="${i.pending_amount}"/>${currencySymbol}</label></td>
</tr>`).join("\n");
console.log(data); // show the data array 

document.querySelector("button").onclick=ev=>
  // show data for AJAX post:
  console.log(Object.values(frm).map(e=>
    ({id:e.closest("tr").children[0].innerText, amnt:e.value})
  ));
```

```css
td,th {text-align:right}
input[type=text] {width:50px}
```

```html
<form name="frm"><table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead><tr>
      <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">Invoice No.</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">Amount</th>
      <th style="width: 15%">Unpaid</th>
      <th style="width: 25%">Payment</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table></form><button>save</button>
```